# Xcode doesn’t support Phone’s iOS 14.7.1

Tags: ios, xcode

What can I do about it? I've seen another post that recommends downloading 14.5 from [here](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/tree/master/DeviceSupport) and renaming the folder 14.7, but that does not work.

Does anyone have an idea on how to go about this?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't support" and the link you've added is just for Firebase samples.

Comment: I copied the wrong link. Now it is updated. I am trying to run my app on my iphone, which is on iOS 14.7.1 and xcode refuses to do so, the message indicates that xcode does not support this version of iOS.

Comment: For me it says "Failed to prepare device for development." I had this issue before 14.7.1, but rebooting the phone fixed it. Now it doesn't work with b1, b3, or b4.

Comment: You can use the 14.6 device support files. To do that, copy the folder that is 14.6 (18F72) and rename it to 14.7.1 (18G82).  It works for me.

I have also tried to copy the device support files 14.6 to 14.7 from https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport .But it didn't help me. 

To know the build number go to Settings -> General -> About and tap on Software Version.

Comment: @Khushneet try 14.7 bianries from here : https://github.com/JinjunHan/iOSDeviceSupport/tree/master/DeviceSupport, they worked for me without updating to anything.

Comment: Rebooting the phone worked for me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Updating to the latest beta of Xcode (Xcode 13 beta 3) worked.

Just not immediately. Left to buy some things, when I came back it worked.

Comment: https://github.com/JinjunHan/iOSDeviceSupport/tree/master/DeviceSupport

If someone can't upgrade XCode the simple solution is to download 14.7 support files and add in folloiwng directory.

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/

Comment: @SkandarMunir I am currently following what you said and it still does not appear 14.7 in the xCode

Comment: cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/14.7/

than run "ls" and share results Please.

Comment: Why did you accept different answer then if this is what fixed the issue?

Comment: @SkandarMunir I followed what you suggested. The folder shows: DeveloperDiskImage.dmg           DeveloperDiskImage.dmg.signature

But I'm still not able to run the application on the device through Xcode.
Can you please help?

Comment: Step 1:  open terminal ===>>>

Step 2: cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/ ===>>>

step 3: sudo mkdir 14.7 (Only perform this if 14.7 is not there). ===>>>

step 4: extract https://github.com/JinjunHan/iOSDeviceSupport/blob/master/DeviceSupport/14.7.zip files into newly created folder "14.7" ===>>>

step 5: restart XCode.

Now it should be working. and Make Sure you 14.7 folder has below files not the Zip file.

DeveloperDiskImage.dmg   DeveloperDiskImage.dmg.signature

Comment: Is there anyway to use it in simulator? I tried downloaded 14.7 but It doesn't show in my simulator list. I still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

i think you should connected you device, and wait xcode copy some suport file from device(will take several minutes). when successful will work fine.

[copying files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k9UL.png)

Comment: my xcode isn't copying anything