# iOS 14.7 Simulator is missing in latest Xcode. How to get it?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

I'm using Xcode 12.5.1 and there is no simulator after 14.5 in download simulators. I need a simulator 14.7 or above. How to get it?

[Simulators List in Xcode 12.5.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdL1I.png)

Comment: Is that something that you cannot find an answer for by running a quick search engine search?

Comment: @ElTomato Not able to find anywhere

Comment: Checkout this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68549513/xcode-doesn-t-support-phone-s-ios-14-7-1

Comment: @vks this is for device support, I need a simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get device support but we can't get simulators except available in the list.